# Random pulse generation in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am new in SystemVerilog world need help.
I am currently developing a small Verilog System which needs a random pulse generation module.

The module needs to randomly generate a pulse based on some probability value.

Could you please help me implementing such a system?

I have found some examples which do random pulse generation.
1. [Random pulse generator](https://opencores.org/projects/random_pulse_generator) however this example doesn't include any probability, and this one is in Verilog.
2. [Pulse generator in System Verilog](https://www.systemverilog.io/randomization#id-1c). This example has some information about probability. But it generates only numbers and I cannot figure out how to change the numbers to pulses, and make the probability work.

Comment: Your number 2 is a simulation model only,. You can not turn that into gates.

Comment: yes, I don't need to turn it into gates. I will use the random pulse generation for testing purposes. Specifically for transient fault simulations.

Answer (score 1):

You can take any [uniform random number](https://opencores.org/projects/random_pulse_generator) and turn it to a probability by comparing it to a value. Given that the largest 32-bit number is **2,147,483,647**, you have a 10% chance of seeing a number less than **214,748,364**. Work your probabilities into a power of 2  simplifies thing. Since the probability of any one of the bits being `1` is 50%, the probability of any set of 3 bits being `1` is 12.5%.